# Unable to add LICENSE/README to NuGet package: error NU5030

Tags: c#, nuget

I have the following `.targets` file that I import in multiple `.csproj` projects:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...         
        <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE</PackageLicenseFile>
        <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
        ...         
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Both `LICENSE` and `README.md` files are next to that `.targets` file which is at root of repository.

But I get the following error:

> error NU5030: The license file 'C:\...\blah\LICENSE' does not exist in the package. [C:\...\blah\whatever\whatever.csproj]

Reference documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-a-license-expression-or-a-license-file
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/add-a-readme-to-your-nuget-package/

**Question:**

How can I get these two files packed onto the NuGet package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the cause [thanks to a clue in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5030) though that wasn't enough to get it working.

Not only there must be `ItemGroup` as well but these shall have `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)`:

```
<Project>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE</PackageLicenseFile>
        <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)LICENSE" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)README.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

To generalize the accepted answer to this question, the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/75622542/482758, and its cross-post https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12463:

The license file specified in the `PackageLicenseFile` build property must be "included in the package" but the mechanism for doing so is subtle and poorly documented.

1. A license file is typically of a type not included in the package *by default*, hence the need for the explicit inclusion via the `None` item (`None` because the file does not require special handling).

   - The path passed to the include item is the correct path to the file, in the form of either an absolute path or a relative path from the build time evaluated location of the include item.

     - Common properties for aid in specifying this path include `SolutionDir`, which is usually the project root; `MSBuildThisFileDirectory`, which is the directory of *the containing file*; and `MSBuildProjectDirectory`, which is the directory of *the project being built*.
2. Besides being selected for inclusion, file inclusion must not be generally disabled via `IncludeContentInPack`, whose value must be `true` and defaults to `true`.
3. The `PackagePath` attribute of the include item determines the virtual path of the license file as it appears in the package, and evaluates to the original file name if left empty.
4. The `PackageLicenseFile`'s value must point to the resolved `PackagePath` value.

The accepted answer to this question worked because the license file was not first explicitly included via some include item (e.g. `None`). We can conclude this because attempting to pack a project containing a path to a file that does not exist produces a `NU5019: File not found` error. Additionally, the specific value of `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)LICENSE` works because that directory contains both the `.targets` file as well as the license file (that path would have resolved incorrectly inside a `.csproj` file).

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75622542/482758 worked because the author had manually disabled `IncludeContentInPack` so no configuration could possibly work. By the time the author corrected that particular mistake the license file had been relocated to the same directory as the file containing the include item, so that answer no longer answers the original question wherein the license file was in an ancestor directory.

To summarize:

If you have a `LICENSE.txt` file in the same directory as the `.sln` file then the following configuration will work no matter which property file it is placed in (`Directory.Build.props`, `Directory.Build.targets`, other `.props` or `.targets`, `.csproj`):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(SolutionDir)LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If the license file is not in the solution directory, or a directory easily reached from the solution directory, one of the other build properties may be more convenient. If the file happens to be in the `.csproj` directory, no path prefix is necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing another answer here as the accepted answer didn't work for me.
If you have a similar folder structure like below:

```
[+] ProjectFolder/
  - LICENSE
  - README
 [+] src/
   - Project.csproj
   - Project.sln
   ...
 [+] test/
   ...
```

Add the following in your .csproj

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\LICENSE">
    <Pack>True</Pack>
    <PackagePath></PackagePath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```