# NuGet Error NU5030 - The license file 'LICENSE.txt' does not exist in the package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have an error in **Visual Studio 17.5.1**. My Visual Studio is up to date.

[image: vs]

**The error**

[image: error]

The license file "LICENSE.md" does not exists in the package. [NuGet Error NU5030](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5030)

---

**My project file (.csproj)**

The files are located in a parent folder. **SolutionFolder**/ProjectFolder

I tried

1. From Microsoft [NuGet Error NU5030](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5030) `<None Include="../LICENSE.md" Pack="true" Visible="true" PackagePath="" />`
2. As it was before this error

```
<None Include="../LICENSE.md">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath></PackagePath>
</None>
```

3. 1 or 2. I copied the files in the same folder of project.

`<None Include="LICENSE.md" Pack="true" Visible="true" PackagePath="" />`

or

```
<None Include="LICENSE.md">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath></PackagePath>
</None>
```

4. `<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)LICENSE.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />`
5. `<None Include="$(SolutionDir)LICENSE.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />`

**Project.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageLicenseFile>License.md</PackageLicenseFile>
        <IncludeContentInPack>false</IncludeContentInPack>
        <VersionPrefix>27.0.0</VersionPrefix>
        <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
        <Version>27.0.0</Version>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="License.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: fullcapture]

Comment: try clearing your NuGet cache and restarting Visual Studio. You can clear your NuGet cache by going to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Clear All NuGet Cache(s).

Comment: no change, error persists.

Comment: See following : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/subscriptions/volume-license.md

Comment: Try adding a license file to the package in your local NuGet cache manually. You can find the NuGet cache in the following locations depending on your OS:

Windows: %UserProfile%.nuget\packages\
macOS/Linux: ~/.nuget/packages/

In the package folder, create a new folder named "license" and add a file named "LICENSE.txt" to that folder. You can copy an existing license file or create a new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to add LICENSE/README to NuGet package: error NU5030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000852/unable-to-add-license-readme-to-nuget-package-error-nu5030)

Comment: All 5 forms specified on this question works fine, after changing  ```IncludeContentInPack = true```. IncludeContentInPack = false, ignores/blocks to add any content when pack operation is executed. If content is not added, the license file does not exists in the nuget package(NuGet Error NU5030).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **IncludeContentInPack** = true

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageLicenseFile>License.md</PackageLicenseFile>

         <IncludeContentInPack>true</IncludeContentInPack>

        <VersionPrefix>27.0.0</VersionPrefix>
        <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
        <Version>27.0.0</Version>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="License.md">
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath></PackagePath>
            <Visible>True</Visible>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

All 5 forms specified on this question works fine, after changing IncludeContentInPack = true.

IncludeContentInPack = false, ignores to add any content when pack operation is executed. If content is not added, the license file does not exists in the nuget package(NuGet Error NU5030).

Comment: Reader, if you end up here you're probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/76185234/482758